# Maven localRepository

Tags: maven

I am currently working on a project that require a fair amount of libraries. I have also install some libraries into the local repository. The next question is how should I write my pom.xml to tell which one should pull from the Internet and which should pull from the local system?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. All repositories are equal in the eyes of maven. You write ordinary <dependency/> elements in your pom, and they work the same either way. Maven will always search the local repository with no special <repository/> elements.

You might find it more convenient in the long term to install a repository manager to share local deployments (Atifactory, Nexus, etc), than to be running install:install-file all the time.